MacOS Python3 Selenium Chrome User Profile not being detected
So for whatever reason, selenium isn't picking up my chrome profile no matter what I do.
On MacOS Sonoma, I can see that the path is as follows. I also double checked it against chrome://version/ (noted at the bottom)
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os

... rest of code

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  pathname= f"/Users/{os.getenv('USER')}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default"
  options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={pathname}")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  cookies = driver.get_cookies()
  print(cookies)

It has to be something tiny but I've no idea what.
Whenever I print out cookies there are none, and therefore, the script I want to write will fail as the driver is never logged into any sites since it has no cookies.
I've tested both Selenium 4.24 latest as of time of writing and 4.16 from a year ago.
The chrome info I have

Google Chrome   128.0.6613.113 (Official Build) (x86_64) 
Revision    9597ae93a15d4d03089b4e9997b1072228baa9ad-refs/branch-heads/6613@{#1429}
OS  macOS Version 14.6.1 (Build 23G93)
JavaScript  V8 12.8.374.24
User agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Command Line    /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Executable Path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
Profile Path    /Users/{MY_NAME_HERE}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default


I could never come up with an answer to this.
The workaround was waiting to start tests until i am done logging in manually to chrome what I wanted to do. I think it's a library limitation.
